# ARM template deployment unhelpful errors, including "The domain name '...' request is invalid. Resource tags are not supported."

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-cli, infrastructure-as-code

Sorry for trying to get "2 answers for the price of 1" ;) but I'm having trouble figuring out the following errors that occur when I deploy my ARM template.

**Error 1:**

```
8:53:07 - 6:50:52 PM - Resource Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames 'cslmh' failed with message '{
18:53:07 -   "error": {
18:53:07 -     "code": "InvalidDomainNameRequest",
18:53:07 -     "message": "The domain name 'cslmh' request is invalid. Resource tags are not supported."
18:53:07 -   }
18:53:07 - }'
```

for my resource

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
  "name": "[variables('CloudServiceName')]",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "Cloud Service"
  },
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames"
}
```

**Error 2:**

```
18:53:07 - 6:51:57 PM - Resource Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallrules 'mysqlserver/AllowAllWindowsAzureIps' failed with message '{
18:53:07 -   "code": "BadRequest",
18:53:07 -   "message": "Invalid value given for parameter tags. Specify a valid parameter value.",
18:53:07 -   "target": null,
18:53:07 -   "details": [],
18:53:07 -   "innererror": []
18:53:07 - }'
```

for my resource

```
{
  "name": "[concat(variables('sqlServerName'), '/', 'AllowAllWindowsAzureIps')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallrules",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "SQL Server Firewall"
  },
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('sqlServerName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
    "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first error - classic resources cannot have tags, drops the `"tags"` property completely
second error - this is a "subresource", I dont think you can have tags on those at all, drop `"tags"` (again).

Also, there is absolutely no point in tagging Azure SQL as Azure SQL, VM as VM, etc.